# How to skip login page if user is already authenticated in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

My react app has the following routes and contexts:

```
const App = () => 
    <AuthContextProvider>
    <IntelContextProvider>
       <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="login" element={<Authentication />} />
            <Route path="register" element={<Registration />} />
                <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            </Route>
       </Routes>
    </IntelContextProvider>
    </AuthContextProvider>
```

Authentication uses an access token stored in memory (`AuthContextProvider`) and a refresh token stored in a HttpOnly cookie.

My home path uses a protected route implemented as follows:

```
export const RequireAuth = () => {
    const location = useLocation()
    const {auth} = useAuth()  
    return (auth?.username ? 
         <Outlet/> : 
         <Navigate to='/login' state={{from: location}} replace/> )
}
```

If the user is not authenticated, it is redirected to /login without any issue. However, I need to do the opposite too:

**If the user has a valid refresh token, when the page is refreshed or the user requests '/register' or '/login pages', then I want the route to be redirected to Home component again.**

I tried to put do the following in the Authentication component:

```
const Authentication = () => {
    
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(null)
    const {values, errors, handleChange, handleSubmit} = useAuthenticationForm(validate)    
    const silentlySignIn = useSilentSignIn()

    useEffect(() => {
        const silentlyLogin = async () => {
            const isAuthenticated = await silentlySignIn()
            if(isAuthenticated) setAuthenticated(true)
        }
        silentlyLogin()
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])
    
    return (
        authenticated ? <Navigate to='/'/> :
        <main className="authentication">
            <form>
               ...
            </form>
        </main>
    );
}
```

Here is my AuthContext:

```
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState()

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And Here is my useSignIn hook:

```
const useSignIn = () => {
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState()
    const { setAuth } = useAuth()

    const signIn = async (payload) => {
        try {
            setError(null)
            const { headers: { authorization: token }, data: { uuid } } = await axiosPrivate.post(`/login`, payload)
            setAuth({ token, uuid, username: payload.username })
            setSuccess(true)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)
            if (!error.response) setError('Sistema temporariamente indisponível.')
            else if (error.response.status === 401) setError('Usuário ou senha inválidos.')
            else setError('Algo deu errado.')
        }
    }
    return [signIn, success, error]
}
```

Here is my useSilentSignIn (to get a new access token if the refresh token is still valid):

```
const useSilentSignIn = () => {
    const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth()

    const silentlySignIn = async () => {
        try {
            if (auth?.uuid) return false
            const response = await axiosPrivate.get('/refresh-token')
            const token = response.headers.authorization
            const uuid = response.data.uuid
            const username = response.data.username
            setAuth(prev => ({ ...prev, token, uuid, username }))
            return true
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Logged out. Please sign in.')
            return false
        }
    }
    return silentlySignIn
}
```

I "solved" the problem, but it first renders the login, then navigates to '/' (due to React component lifecycle). It does not seem like a good solution, it is ugly, and I would need to do the same for '/register' or any similar route.

How to implement something efficient for such a problem?

Github of the project: https://github.com/lucas-ifsp/CTruco-front

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to add this logic to the `Authentication`  rendered on the `"/login"` path. In this case you create another route protection component that does the inverse of the `RequireAuth` component. This is commonly referred to as an "anonymous route" that you only want users that ***are not*** authenticated to access.

If the user ***is*** authenticated then render a redirect to any non-anonymous path, otherwise render the outlet for the nested route to render its `element` into. While the auth status is being checked and still undefined, you can render null or any sort of loading indicator to make the route protection wait until the state value updates.

Example:

```
export const AnonymousRoute = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuth();

  if (auth === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc...
  }

  return auth.username
    ? <Navigate to='/' replace /> 
    : <Outlet/>;
}
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    <Route element={<AnonymousRoute />}>
      <Route path="login" element={<Authentication />} />
      <Route path="register" element={<Registration />} />
    </Route>
    <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew Resse. I tried to implement it. The problem is that the axios request is async and react does not await the promise to render or route. Because the access token is in the memory, I need to request a new one in the backend if the page is refreshed. How to wait the answer before the return in the AnonynousRoute?

Comment: @LucasBueno What is the "don't know the auth status yet" state for `auth.user`? In other words, what is the initial state value for it?

Comment: The initial state is undefined. 


export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState()

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default AuthContext

Comment: @LucasBueno I couldn't find any auth context code in your repo, but based upon the code you just shared it looks like the initial `auth` value is undefined. I'll update my answer with logic to handle waiting.

Comment: Resse, I updated the description if useSignIn custom hook

Comment: @LucasBueno Sorry if I'm just missing something here, but are these `useSignIn` and `useSilentSignIn` hooks relevant to your question regarding preventing access to the `"/login"` route for authenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

Your `authenticated` state has three possible states (yay JavaScript):

- Authenticated (true)
- Non-authenticated (false)
- Not yet known (null)

You could convert them to string enums for clarity, but for conciseness, this is how you would handle all three cases:

```
if (authenticated === null) return <Spinner /> // Or some other loading indicator
return (
        authenticated ? <Navigate to='/'/> :
        <main className="authentication">
            <form>
               ...
            </form>
        </main>
    );
```